# undefined symbol: _ZTVNSt7__cxx1119basic_istringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIc.. while importing pyndri

Tags: python, anaconda, libstdc++

pyndri installed successfully, but when I am importing it, I get the following error:

`undefined symbol:_ZTVNSt7__cxx1119basic_istringstreamIcSt11char_traits....`

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from anaconda 4.2.0 environment libstdc++, run

`strings ANACONDA_HOME/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX`

You might see following output

`GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH`

As you see there is no GLIBCXX_3.4.20 in anaconda 4.2.0 libstdc++

Now run the following commands to solve the problem:

`cd ANCONDA_HOME/lib
 rm libstdc++.so.6.0.19
 ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.0.19`

Hopefully this should solve the problem.